# How to call a function from the App class in the cppwinrt template project from MainPage

Tags: c++-winrt

I am working within the Visual Studio template project for a cppWinRT Blank App.

What I would like to do is make a call to a function defined in `MainPage` from the `OnLaunched` function inside the `App` class.

So far my theory is that I need is something along those lines:

```
MainPage* mainPageImpl = from_abi<BlankApp1::implementation::MainPage>(/*somehow get a pointer to the MainPage instance*/);
mainPageImpl->myFunction();
```

However I am not sure if this is the correct approach.

Comment: That looks wrong. When entering `App::OnLaunched`, your `MainPage` instance likely hasn't been created yet (surely the case in a default C++/WinRT Blank App). This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What is it, that you are ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: I've actually solved my initial problem in an entirely different way, so this is mainly because of curiosity and to help me understand the application better. So in reality it doesn't absolutely have to be from the App class.

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_self` to convert projection class to implementation class.

```
MainPage* mainPageImpl = get_self<MainPage>(Window::Current().Content().try_as<Frame>().Content().try_as<BlankApp1::MainPage>());
mainPageImpl->myFunction();
```